# Modifying grep output to have field descriptions

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep, cut

I am trying to write a short script to search for all users whose first name matches whatever is in names.txt

The result should be in the following example format:

Username: tom01, Full Name: Tom Bennett, Home Directory: /home/users/tom01

```
grep -f name.txt /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1,5,6 | awk '{print '{"Username: "$1", Full Name: "$2", Home Directory: "$3}'
```

I'm pretty far from the answer here it seems, and totally stuck about which commands I should use. Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip piping to `cut` with something like this:

```
grep -f name.txt /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print "User name", $1, "Full name", $5, "Home directory", $6}'
```

Note that the `awk -F: '{print "User name", $1, "Full name", $5, "Home directory", $6}'` uses `-F:` to set `:` as field separator and then prints the required text and data.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't too far off then, just missed the syntax a bit lol.

Answer (score 2):

You are not very far at all, it works with just minor modifications:

```
grep -f name.txt /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1,5,6 | awk --field-separator : '{print "Username: "$1", Full Name: "$2", Home Directory: "$3}'
```

Not sure it handles the corner cases (people with no name set etc), but for a quick hack it is perhaps enough.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I may prefer not to use [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) or [cut](/questions/tagged/cut) utilities if [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is used. This reduce the overhead of starting unnecessary processes and makes the [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) script just a little bit more complex.

My assumption is that the 5th field contains the full name of the user and the name.txt contains the first names You are looking for.

My [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)-less solution is:

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR { fn = fn ? $0"|"fn : $0; next }
$5 ~ "(^| )("fn") " { print "User name: "$1", Full name: "$5", Home directory: "$6}
' name.txt /etc/passwd
```

This script reads the first file first and create a pipe delimited string of first names to form an ERE. Then reads the second file and tries to match the first names against the full name of the user. It matches just the exact first names. This has an improvement compared to other solutions. This works properly even if family name contains (or equals) a christian name. See example:

Input files:

```
cat <<XXX >name.txt
Joe
Thomas
XXX

cat <<XXX >passwd
user01:*:500:501:Joan Thomasson:/home/user01
user02:*:500:501:Thomas Joanson:/home/user02
user03:*:500:501:Joan Thomas Joanson:/home/user03
user04:*:500:501:Joan Thomas:/home/user04
Thomas:*:500:501:Joan Thomas:/home/Thomas
XXX
```

Output:

```
User name: user02, Full name: Thomas Joanson, Home directory: /home/user02
User name: user03, Full name: Joan Thomas Joanson, Home directory: /home/user03
```

I hope this could help!